# Failed routes in Laravel: parameter arrives broken

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have bug on routes of laravel. I have the following routes:

```
Route::any('/{any}/{from}-to-{info}.html', function($any, $from, $info) {
        return $from.$info;
    });
```

When the URL is: /density/ounce-gallon-us-to-kilotonne-kiloliter.html

The variable $info is broken without "to" in kilotonne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
Route::any('/{any}/{from}-to-{info}.html', function($any, $from, $info) {
    return $from.$info;
})->where('from','[^\/]*')->where('info','[^\/]*');
```

It gives: `ounce-gallon-uskilotonne-kiloliter` as output